# Android Studio : How to reformat code of entire project?

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea, code-formatting

I am looking for a way to reformat code of entire project, which is available for individual files via `code` -> `reformat code`.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Right click on app folder in android studio , from left panel . You will see the option for `Reformat Code`

Answer (score 5):

Select your sources folder like "java" and use the command **Ctrl + Alt + L**

OR

Right click on source folder say for instance "java" and select "Reformat Code". A dialog "Reformat Code" would be shown. Select checkbox "Include subdirectories" and hit "Run".

[image]